# controlling JSON serialization of an array

Tags: ruby, json, serialization

I am working on a project that uses Ruby and Sinatra to publish a web service.  The problem that I'm having is that I can't figure out how to get arrays to serialize properly.  I have two routes.

```
get '/Post' do
    postId= params[:id]
    my_post = Post.new(BSON::ObjectId(postId))
    return my_post.to_json() #runs the to_json method in post
end

get '/SourcePosts' do
    sourceId = params[:source]
    my_source = Source.new(BSON::ObjectId(sourceId)) #returns an array of Posts
    return my_source.get_posts.to_json() #ignores the to_json method in post
end
```

The first `Post` works as I expect, calling my custom to_json method which omits lazy loaded attributes.  The second `SourcePosts` ignores my override and dumps everything, including the attributes that require a database dip to load.  My question: how can I get ruby to either call my method or otherwise ignore expensive attributes when serializing arrays to JSON?

Comment: Not sure I understand your issue correctly, but you shouldn't use `return` keyword in code blocks, because it can broke logic of `get` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that there was a left over `require 'active_support/all'` in the model class which was interfering with array serialization.